# Internet Explorer - CSS box-Shadow on table not working for IE browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, css-tables, box-shadow

I tried `box-shadow` for `tr` in Table and works fine for Chrome but not working for IE browser. I checked almost all suggested links on *Stack Overflow* but I couldn't get any reason and answer.

This is the example I used http://jsfiddle.net/c_Dhananjay/h9tx9tpx/
where i do :

```
    table tbody tr:hover {
        background-color:#13326b;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
        box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
    }

    table tbody tr {
        height:100px;
    }
```

I hope this may look like a duplicate question but hope you  will show correct path for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied `box-shadow` on `td` instead of `tr` with some changes in css and that works for chrome / safari / IE11 / EDGE

Here is working link : https://jsfiddle.net/h9tx9tpx/2/

Working code :

```
      // css file
        table tbody tr {
            background-color:#13326b;
            color:#ffffff;
            text-shadow: 1px 2px #000000;
        }

        table tbody tr {
            height:70px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: separate;  
        }

        td:first-child:before{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            content:'';
            position:absolute;

            left:0;
            right:2px;

            display: block;
            height: 60px;
            box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than applying the box shadow to the row you can instead target the first td of the row. Visually, it gives the exact same result.

```
table tbody tr:hover td:first-child {  
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 0px -1px #ff0000;
}
```

**Old Answer**

According to caniuse.com

> Edge and IE up to 11 suppress box-shadow in tables with border-collapse:collapse

In order to support your box-shadows in IE you'll need to add the following block of code to your stylesheet:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;  
}
```

In your example this doesn't affect the styling of your table too much so you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks but it seems not working in both Edge as well as IE11 .
Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/h9tx9tpx/1/  where I tried your suggestion.

Comment: Apologies, I suggested this blind. I've since tried in Safari (debugging IE as a User-Agent) and the updated code works. Please let me know otherwise.